# How to make global imports in Python?

Tags: python

So I have create three python files lets call them p1, p2 and p3. Both p1 and p2 need p3 and p1 imports p2. I was wondering if there was a way I could omit importing p3 in p2 since I am already importing p3 in p1 and also p2 in p1.

p1, p2 and p3 all contain functions and classes.

Edit:

in p1 I do this:

```
import p3 as p
```

and in p2 I call some function from p using p.somefunction but it throws a global name 'p' not found.

Comment: Imports *are* global - when you import the same module a second time it's just looked up instead of actually re-loaded. However, you need to specify the relevant inputs in every file that requires them.

Comment: If something has already been imported, it won't be imported again, however many times you call `import [module name]`

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this?

Comment: well, I am doing a import  p3 as p in p1 but in p2 when I call a function from p3 like p.somefunction it throws a global name 'p' not defined.

Comment: No, there's no way to do that, and thanks Guido for that. What module needs and what it has access to must be clear by looking into the module code, and must not depend on how it is imported.

Comment: @user17282 could you provide an *actual example* of what you're doing, with three example files? It's much easier just to `import p3` in both `p1` and `p2`. If `p1` imports `p2` and `p3` **why on earth would that inject `p3` into `p2`?!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can omit importing `p3` in `p1`, since you can access the imported version by doing `p2.p3` in file `p1`

Also there is no harm in importing, because second time you import a module, it will just look into memory for the already imported one.

Comment: But note that this forces `p1` to depend on `import p3` being in `p2` - if the import in `p2` is changed to an alias (`import p3 as foo`) or select specific names (`from p3 import bar`) that breaks `p1`.